# Spaces around all hyphens in a string without double-up

Tags: regex

I'm after a regex that puts spaces around each "-" in a string, eg.

```
02 jaguar-leopard, tiger-panther 08
```

would become

```
02 jaguar - leopard, tiger - panther 08
```

---

Note that if the "-" already has spaces around it, no changes are to be made, eg.

```
02 jaguar - leopard, tiger - panther 08
```

should not become

```
02 jaguar  -  leopard, tiger  -  panther 08
```

---

The number of hyphens are unknown in advance.

Thanks for any ideas...

Edit:
I'm not actually using a language for this. I'm using [Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer) (a mass file renaming utility). There are two fields in the renamer GUI, "Expression" and "New name" to provide inputs. This is from the help file as an example:

> Swapping artist and title from mp3 file names:
>
> Expression = (.*) - (.*).mp3
>
> New name = $2 - $1.mp3

and

> Extract episode number and title from series video files with episode number as SnnEmm followed by title:
>
> Expression = Code.Quantum.S([0-9]{2})E([0-9]{2}).(.*).FRENCH.XViD.avi
>
> New name = Code Quantum - $1$2 - $3.avi

Comment: A regex can help with the matching half of your requirements.  For help with the replacement half, tell us what language you're using.

Comment: If you didn't want to use a regex, you could simply; 1. replace all instances of ' -' (space dash) and '- ' (dash space) with '-' (dash), and then 2. replace all '-' (dash) with ' - ' (space dash space). This will achieve the required behavior (as long as multiple spaces aren't present).

Answer (score 4):

Replace `_*-_*` with `_-_` (replace the underscores with spaces before using the pattern).

This way, any existing spaces around the hyphen will be replaced by the newly inserted spaces.

Comment: This is the cleanest suggestion I've seen so far. I don't believe you need brackets around the space, though, I think ` *- *` will suffice, as strange as it looks.

Answer (score 2):

Search:

```
(?:(\S)| )-(?:(\S)| )
```

Replace:

```
$1 - $2
```

Note that your tool may use backslashes for back references, it might need `\1 - \2` instead.

Comment: Because both sides are optional, this will match absolutely any hyphen and will add a space on either side. This is undesirable for hyphens already preceded or followed by a space.

Comment: @SeanJohnson right. So I need to capture the space too - how does that look now?

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely need two expressions to accomplish this task.

1. Replace `(?<=\S)-` with " -"
2. Replace `-(?=\S)` with "- "

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/UTUZADe/1/edit?js,console (I had to use a different method for #1, JS does not support look-ahead assertions unfortunately)